# MATCH and rearrange in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm not sure how to explain this. Hope the below image will be helpful to understand what I need.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kysOw.jpg

Basically I want to match "BATCH A" to "BATCH B" and then re-arrange "BATCH A" and "FRUIT" in the same order as "BATCH B"

Comment: Is the matching 1:1 or can BATCH A match multiple entries under BATCH B and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VLOOKUP function.

Comment: That wouldn't rearrange the data though

Comment: @xml If all of the columns on the right hand are obtained into new columns using VLOOKUP, then a copy and paste values is done on the obtained data, followed by deleting the original right hand data that is no longer needed. Shall we provide a step in the right direction and let go, or spoon feed?

Comment: Ok, sounds good. Your comment should be illuminating enough, see what the poster says.

Comment: Thank you. I looked up the VLOOKUP function and job done. Thanks for the support Tarik.